# how to extend a recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've tried to make a list with selectionnable elements. I can click on button and it select the element, but it also select other elements regularly in the list. I notice that for example, when I select the first element, all ten elements are selectionned too. It is obviously a problem for me... Can you help me please ?
here is my activity

```
val transactionChooser = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transactionChooser.replace(R.id.container_lowerLegs, ChooserLowerLegs(this))
        transactionChooser.addToBackStack(null)
        transactionChooser.commit()
```

and here is my adapter

```
class SelectionAdapter(
        val context: MyActivity1,
        private val chooserList: ArrayList<ChooserModel>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectionAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    //boite pour ranger les composants à contrôler
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val exerciceImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_selection)
        val likedIcon: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.button_liked)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_selection, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // récupérer les infos du muscle group
        val currentItem = chooserList[position]

        //vérifier si item liked
        fun updateStar() {
            if (currentItem.liked) {
                holder.likedIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_foreground)
            } else {
                holder.likedIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_foreground)
            }
        }

        //mettre à jour les infos du muscle group
        holder.exerciceImage.setImageResource(currentItem.drawable)
        holder.likedIcon.setOnClickListener {
            currentItem.liked = !currentItem.liked
            updateStar()
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = chooserList.size
}
```

and finally my Fragment :

```
open class ChooserLowerLegs(
            private val context: MyActivity1
    ) : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list_item, container, false)

            val chooserList = arrayListOf<ChooserModel>()
            chooserList.add(
                    ChooserModel(
                            R.string.home_page_first_button,
                            R.string.first_picture,
                            R.drawable.bas_des_jambes_1,
                            false
                    )
            )
            chooserList.add(
                    ChooserModel(
                            R.string.home_page_first_button,
                            R.string.second_picture,
                            R.drawable.bas_des_jambes_3,
                            false
                    )
            )
            chooserList.add(
                    ChooserModel(
                            R.string.home_page_first_button,
                            R.string.third_picture,
                            R.drawable.bas_des_jambes_5,
                            false
                    )
            )

            // récupérer le recyclerview

            val verticalRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.Vertical_recycler_view_grid)
            verticalRecyclerView.adapter = SelectionAdapter(context, chooserList)
            verticalRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(MuscleItemDecoration())
            return view
        }
}
```

Also, I wanted to show my items in a grid, not in a linear view, but I have no clue for how doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set layout manager to your recycle view,

To set GridLayout with 2 Columns:

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2)
val mAdapter = YourAdapter(context = activity!!,list = list)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
```

Now, for a single selection from out of 10 records in the list. take a Boolean variable in your Model class that you are passing in your Adapter class. when clicking on the item of Recycleview, take for loop to make another item boolean variable to false and set the item you want to show as selected set it as a True after For loop completed. And last to show some mark as selected write code in Adapter class using the Boolean variable you have taken in your Model class:

for example : Listener of Recycleview item

```
mAdapter.clickListener{ pos, model ->
   var entity = model as YourModel

   list.forEach {
      model.isSelected = false
   }
   list[i].isSelected = true   
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```